# nestjs how to disable ScheduleModule(@Cron) in tests

Tags: node.js, cron, nestjs

This is my app.module.ts in nestjs:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { CatsModule } from './cats/cats.module';

@Module({
 imports: [CatsModule, ScheduleModule.forRoot()],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

And this is my tests beforeEach:

```
    const moduleRef = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [AppModule],
    })
      .compile();

    app = moduleRef.createNestApplication();
    await app.init();
```

I want all @Cron() decorators to be disables in tests.
I want to disable `ScheduleModule` totally for tests.

How can it be done

(The motivation is to avoid unexpected site effects in tests)